# why not seeing hybrid connection selection option in logic app workflow new connection configuration for sql get rows action

Tags: azure, connection, gateway, hybrid

using azure logic app workflow sql getrows action and setting up a new connection that should use an already created and configured hybrid connection. I do not get the ui option to select the hybrid connection or data gateway that is to be used. trying with both a hybrid connection and data gateway I no longer see either hybrid connection or data gateway dropdown options. why?

looking for documentation

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of your design diagram

Comment: it's just an azure logic app with a data gateway but the azure portal ui never shows the option to use the data gateway with the workflow sql action when creating a new connection. in the past I have seen the option to use data gateway.

Answer (score 0):

To see additional options like Data Gateway, use v2 or higher of the workflow action. The default action (first in the list) does not offer additional options. The v2 action toward the bottom of the list does offer additional options.